# zabbix_get and AWK/substr - ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED: Too many parameters

Tags: shell, awk, monitoring, zabbix

I'm trying to use Zabbix to gather information about 500 errors in Apache logs. I thought, I will use zabbix_get to execute command on Agent's OS, however when trying to test that, I get `ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED: Too many parameters.` error. At first, I tried to escape all `"` and other special characters, however without any success. When trying to debug the command (which works well locally, without using zabbix_get) I found that the issue is probably somewhere close to AWK and substr. I would appreciate if anyone could take a look...

`tail -n 1000 /content/logs/httpd/*_access.log | awk -v d1="$(date --date='-5 min' '+%_d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')" -v d2="$(date '+%_d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')" 'substr($5,2) > d1 && substr($5,2) < d2 || substr($5,2) ~ d2' | cut -d" " -f10 | grep "500" | wc -l`

Sample Input:
`IP IP - - [21/Jan/2019:03:14:06 -0500] "GET /path HTTP/1.1" 200 2068 referrer "UserAgent" 7634.
IP IP - - [21/Jan/2019:03:14:06 -0500] "GET /path HTTP/1.1" 500 1 "-" "UserAgent" 1892`

Output:
`1`

I would like to execute command listed above every 5 minutes to count number of entries with 500 error which happened during previous 5 minutes.

I know that I can always create a script but if I could avoid doing that...

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post sample input and sample expected output in your post and let us know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, sure I can! Added to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by `I know that I can always create a script but if I could avoid doing that... `? You ARE asking for help to create a new script or modify your existing script, right?

Comment: @EdMorton, I meant that I can create shell script on the VM and run that by zabbix_get, however I would like to stay with one-liner.

Comment: You can cram any script onto one line. Asking for a "one-liner" isn't a great goal and asking for that usually discourages people from helping you as it means you're trying to find a brief script rather than a robust, portable, efficient, etc. script.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `zabbix_get` you could create a `system.run[blablabla]`.

However, you should user the native [log file monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items) feature: use the `logrt.count` or `log.count` functions to extract the number of matching lines.

Comment: Yes, by using zabbix_get I invoke system.run command. I will look into log monitoring, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date compare is correct (in fact not the case due to the letter of month)
try this:

```
  tail -n 1000 /content/logs/httpd/*_access.log | awk -v d1="$(date --date='-5 min' '+%_d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')" -v d2="$(date '+%_d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')" '{Ti=substr($5,2)};( Ti > d1 && Ti <= d2 ) && $10 ~ /5[0-9][0-9]/  {Cnt++;print $10} END{print Cnt+0}'
```

you can also skip the tail using only awk directly, it's fast enough with few change:

```
awk -v d1="$(date --date='-5 min' '+%_d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')" -v d2="$(date '+%_d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')" '($5 < "[" d1){next};{Ti=substr($5,2)};( Ti > d1 && Ti <= d2 ) && $10 ~ /5[0-9][0-9]/  {Cnt++;print $10} END{print Cnt+0}' /content/logs/httpd/*_access.log
```

you can also limit the *_access.log with a `$( find /content/logs/httpd -name *_access.log -mmin -6)`